# Marriage Dates not included in detailed reports

Tags: marriage-records, gramps

My question is about reporting of marriage dates in GRAMPS output reports.  I am using GRAMPS AIO64-5.1.2-1.  When I print detailed reports the marriage dates ARE NOT shown in the various reports.  I have gone back and checked the family data and the correct marriage dates are properly shown in the individual people and family data.  I have also tried using the GRAMPS graphical reports and they also DO NOT show the marriage date in the output reports.  How do I enter the marriage dates into the database so they are correctly shown in the various reports?

Comment: How did you enter the marriage dates? Which field in which screen? Can you give the names of some reports that do not work for you? When you say the date is not displayed, does it display "marriage date: nothing" or do you see no marriage mention at all?

Comment: Exactly which reports did you run?  I just verified that marriage data is in the `PersonEverything`, the `Family Group Report` and the `Family Sheet`, as well as the `Family Descendant Tree` (when you tell it to).